# Is it possible to use OSRM in order to calculate routing into a building?

Tags: feature-dataset, open-source-routing-machine

I would like to know: If we save in the OSRM server a dataset of points stored from a GPS tracker into a building (a flat one).  Is it possible to request the server in order to find the shortest way from one point to another?

The aim would be to help customers/employees find their way into a place that does not have any standard GIS data like roads, streets, and so on (like a stadium used during a convention, a zoo, an amusement park, etc).

Comment: You would have to enrich the topology with these points to route on them.

Comment: And how could I enrich the topology please? @TimothyDalton

Answer (score 1):

Yes, as the comments suggest this can be done.

What has to happen is that the base geometries if the stadium, zoo, or other, have to be linear and they have to have measures applied to them. Typically these are walkways,  isles, seating rows. The measures are typically unit lengths starting from some origin local to each feature.

Thinking of these isles or walkwsys as though they are streets may help you decide how to use measures on them. Most streets have a 0 block and increase in addresses from there.

In stadiums, the isles have numbers, so the main walkway can be measured from one isle to another. Some zoos already do this by naming their walks and addressing the exhibits along the walks.